# "Failed to lookup instance on (localdb)" when the full instance name is "(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB"

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to do a simple select query to my database with node.js via the `mssql` package, but the it seems that the server property of my connection string doesn't take the full string and stop at `(localdb)` instead of the full server name which is `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Code :

```
let sql = require('mssql');
  sql.connect({
        server:'(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB',
        database:'xxx',
        options:{
            trustedConnection:true
        }
    },function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err);

        var request = new sql.Request();

        request.query('simple query',function(err,recordset){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.send(recordset);
        })
    })
```

Error :

> ConnectionError: Failed to lookup instance on (localdb) - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (localdb)

Was there a change on how `mssql` in node checks the instance link or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: You can try this link: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/access-sql-server-in-nodejs

Comment: LocalDB requires Named Pipes connections and Tedious, behind the mssql library, only talks TCP/IP. [Does tedious support localdb? #348](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/348).